# Importance of styling order

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding in vanilla Javascript. Why does the order of styling matter? For example in pseudo code:

```
<head>
   .show {display: block;}

   .drop {display: none;}
</head>
<body>
   <button id="btn" onclick></button>

   <div id="example" class="drop">
      <p>sample text</p>
   </div>
</body>

<script>
   document.getElementById('btn').onclick = () => {(function(){
      document.getElementById('example').classList.toggle('show');
   })();}
</script>
```

If I were to execute this code, and press the button, it won't show the sample text, however, if I were to switch the order of the styling:

```
<head>
   .drop {display: none;}

   .show {display: block;}
</head>
```

The sample text will appear from this order. Two questions:

1. Why does the order matter?
2. I have a button that toggles the class, so the order shouldn't matter regardless since I'm only activating the classes within the button and toggle method right?

Comment: Thats the nature of Cascading Style Sheets, it's that Cascading part that is messing with you.

Comment: @AdamH: Actually, Cascading means parent-child inheritance.  You mean precedence.

Comment: @SLaks well I feel we are arguing over semantics. I'll argue that the precedence is the styles Cascading down the chain of assigned classes in the order they were assigned and that is the style cascading down to the element. Then you will argue that I'm wrong and the actual term is precedence. Let's just skip all that and go straight to laughing about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Css and JavaScript are very similar. If you write something later, then it overrides the previous value

JavaScript

```
let myNumber = 5;
myNumber = 10;

console.log(myNumber); // 10
```

Same applites to CSS

CSS

```
.show {display: block;}

.drop {display: none;}
```

If you have show and drop on the same element, then it will go through the css file and find `.show`, set the element style `display:block`, then after it will find `.drop` and set the element style `display:none`.

You can override this order with `!important`, but using `!important` is often a symptom of something else that is wrong.

Comment: That's not quite true; precedence prevents that.

Comment: @SLaks Can you explain why that is? I find his explanation is a lot easier to comprehend

Comment: @rgex: More-specific selectors are not overridden by less-specific selectors. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 3):

CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets. By design, they assume you will have multiple conflicting rules. What you need to know comes down to [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the rules and order.

In your case these two rules have exactly the same specificity (both have one class only), so in this case the later one will take precedence, because it's later.

However if the first one was two classes, or an id, or a class and tag name, etc... then it would take precedence because of a higher specificity.